# Shadowing of optional function arguments?

Tags: functions, packages

I am trying to define two different packages that process some information in a different way.
These packages have functions into them with optional arguments. 
The names of the optional arguments happen to collide and Mathematica is complaining about shadowing of these symbols.
Here is an example of my code:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage1`"]
Options[f] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
f[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]};
EndPackage[]

BeginPackage["MyPackage2`"]
Options[g] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
g[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]};
EndPackage[]
```

Mathematica complains:

```
"Symbol "a" appears in multiple contexts ({"MyPackage2`", "MyPackage1`"}); definitions in context "MyPackage2`" may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions."
```

Now I try:

```
Needs["MyPackage1`"]
Needs["MyPackage2`"]
f[a -> 3, b -> 4]
g[a -> 1, b -> 2]
(* {3,4}  {1,2} *)
```

Thus, the functions work correctly as they are supposed to, but Mathematica is insisting on coloring `a` and `b` in red everywhere and that they appear in different contexts.

Is there a way to solve this problem? (without renaming `a` and `b` as they represent the same input data in the two packages, would be non-intuitive to change their names).

Comment: The strategy done by the built-in packages was to declare symbols common to both packages in a ``Common` `` context.

Comment: For private options you can also use strings.

Comment: @FJRA, if you'll indulge me a rant: one peeve I've always had since *Mathematica* started using strings for options was that one cannot attach usage messages to strings, and thus one cannot use `?` to learn more about them without having to refer to the docs.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. that's indeed a very good point. Anyway in private functions (if I ever document them :) ), I include the options in the main usage message of the function, and not on each option. But in bigger projects the usage of a `Common` context is many times necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Guesswhoitis., So, I should add an extra `BeginPackage` and name the context `common\`` for example. But then, how do I refer to the symbols in the arguments? `Common\`` even in the function options  definition? Or just use them directly? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, as I am not writing this message from a computer with a proper *Mathematica* installation, I have refrained from writing an answer on this. Nevertheless: if you'll look at the LegacyPackages folder in your installation, you'll find package files in there named `Common.m`, where the shared symbols are declared. Then, in the package that will be using these shared symbols, there is an additional declaration in `BeginPackage[]` for the ``Common` `` context.

Comment: But nothing beats seeing the examples for yourself. Study the ``Statistics` `` legacy packages as an example of using a `Common.m` package.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Got it, many thanks for your help, highly appreciate it.

Comment: If you manage to hash it out, you can answer your own question, and I can offer comments if I see it fit to do so. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guided by `Guess who it is` comments, I managed to do it.
The solution as suggested by his comments is to define a common package say `` MyCommon` `` to declare the symbols and both `` MyPackage1` `` and `` MyPackage2` `` should use `` Needs[MyCommon`] `` to get the symbols. Also as he mentioned, this allows for documenting the symbols as well.

Here is my current implementation to solve the problem:

```
(* Package MyCommon` *)
BeginPackage["MyCommon`"]
If [ Not @ ValueQ[a::usage], a::usage = "This is a" ];
If [ Not @ ValueQ[b::usage], b::usage = "This is b" ];
EndPackage[]

(* Package MyPackage1` *)
BeginPackage["MyPackage1`", "MyCommon`"] (* MyCommon` passed as Needs *)
Options[f] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
f[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]};
EndPackage[]

(* Package MyPackage2` *)
BeginPackage["MyPackage2`", "MyCommon`"] (* MyCommon` passed as Needs *)
Options[g] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
g[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]};
EndPackage[]
```

Now, testing this implementation:

```
Needs["MyPackage1`"]
Needs["MyPackage2`"]
f[a -> 3, b -> 4]
g[a -> 1, b -> 2]
(*{3,4} {1,2}*)
```

which works without any complaints about the shadowing of the optional arguments symbols.

Comment: Nicely done. :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis & Bichoy I'm not sure what is the real context but including all usage or just symbol names in one additional package, for packages which are separate, just for purpose of not shadowing seems to be not so handy and scalable. It often happens that I miss the point of the question so tell my if I did again :)

Comment: @Kuba, what would you suggest, then?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. In general case, when those packages are meant to be separate but the options are meant to be exported I'd use string names and if you miss usage you can add it to usage of the function they are options of. I don't claim it is better here but seems to be more stable for general case.

Comment: @Kuba, if the packages are meant to be completely independent, maybe, so you replace the annoyance of undocumentable strings with long-ish usage messages for the function proper. But for closely-related packages, a `Common.m` package looks more attractive to me.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Notice that the fact those may be closely related packages does not mean the same option will do the same thing in both packages. So different usage names are desired. Still depends of the context of course. Maybe it's just a matter of taste, but I think it is good to leave those comments here as on topic.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the useful comments. The above implementation fits exactly with what I am trying to achieve. In this project, Package1 and Package2 deals with the same data. Basically, Package1 does everything I/O related: it is supposed to read a database of designs and generate substitution rules for all the design parameters depending on the requested design ( So, for eg, one asks for design AB024, they get back {designName->AB024, a-> 1, b->2 , c->32.2, ...} ). It is also responsible for saving back any changes made to any design parameter through appropriate functions + new entries.

Comment: @Kuba ...  Package2 actually computes the performance of this design through a set of functions that have all possible design parameters as optional arguments (not all designs have all parameters). Thus, the logical functionality of the two packages is completely separate, but they share the name of the parameters between them. So, the above implementation makes sense in my case. 
But thanks for the useful notes and discussion, I will keep for next time :)